# getting error cx-storefront is not known element Spartacus Angular storefront in SAP Hybris

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

```
ERROR in 'cx-storefront' is not a known element:
```

1. If 'cx-storefront' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'cx-storefront' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]
   ")

Comment: The `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` warning normally indicates that component (`cx-storefront` in this case) hasn't been imported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838084/cx-media-cx-carousel-not-emitting-data

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by below two things in Angular >^9.0

1. disable Ivy compiler option in tsconfig.app.json

   "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableIvy": false
   }
2. adding below configuration in the src/app/app.module.ts

   B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
   backend: {
   occ: {
   baseUrl: environment.occBaseUrl,
   prefix: '/occ/v2/'
   },
   },
   context: {
   baseSite: ['electronics-spa'],
   },
   })

Where occBaseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002' is the property defined in the environment configuration.

Comment: What helped you was actually *importing `B2cStorefrontModule`*. It exports the `StorefrontComponent` so it's accessible in your `AppComponent`. Ivy is the recommended render engine. Thus *IVY shouldn't be disabled* if not having good enough arguments to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your tsconfig.json file and mark strictTemplates as false. This worked for me.

"angularCompilerOptions": {
"strictTemplates": false
}